# Pass data between two independent components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building a web-application with ReactJS and that needs me to implement a Search. So far, the search has been implemented (I'm using [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) library for this) using a form with an input element. The form is implemented in the NavBar and after the user types a search-query, he is redirected to 'localhost:3000/search' URL where he can see the results corresponding to his query.

Here is the code I'm using for the form in the SearchBar.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ReactComponent as SearchLogo } from '../../lib/search-logo.svg';

const SearchBar = () => {
 const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState({ query: '' });

 const searchQueryHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery({ query: event.target.value });
 };

 const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "/search";
 }

 return (
    <Form inline className="nav-search-form" onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <SearchLogo className="search-logo" />
        <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search spaces of interest"
            className="nav-search"
            value={searchQuery.query}
            onChange={searchQueryHandler} />
    </Form>
 );
}
export default SearchBar;
```

I need to display the corresponding results in another SearchPage which will take the query from this component after submission and then display the results. Here is the code I have written for it.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SpaceCardGrid from '../space-card-grid/space-card-grid';
import useSpaces from '../../utils/firebase/hooks/useSpaces';
import moment, { Moment } from 'moment';
import { roundTime } from '../../utils/date';
import Fuse from 'fuse.js';



const SearchPage = (queries) => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState<[Moment, Moment]>([moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())]);
    const [time, setTime] = useState([roundTime(), roundTime(30)]);
    const [dateRangeType, setDateRangeType] = useState<'week' | 'day' | 'now'>('day');
    const spaceCardGridRef = useRef(null);
    const spaces = useSpaces(dateRangeType, date, time, 0);


    const options = {
        shouldSort: true,
        keys: ['title', 'description'],
    };
    const fuse = new Fuse(spaces, options);
    let filteredspaces = spaces;

    if (queries.query !== '') {
        const result = fuse.search(queries.query);
        console.log(result);
        filteredspaces = [];
        result.forEach((space) => {
            filteredspaces.push(space.item);
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid className="bottom-container">
                <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
                    <Col>
                        <div className="grid-root">
                            <SpaceCardGrid spaces={filteredspaces} spaceCardGridRef={spaceCardGridRef} />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Just for additional information `useSpaces()` is a function that gives me all the data (and it does so correctly), and `filteredspaces` is the final results array that I wish to display on the screen. All these things are perfectly working.

I'm stuck on how to pass the query between the two components though. The `queries` I have used in `SearchPage(queries)` is a dummy variable. I'm new to React, and I have learned about Redux, but it seems a lot of work (I might be wrong) for simply passing a value between 2 components. As you can clearly observe, the components aren't related but are independent. Is there a simple way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `useContenxt` along with `useReducer` hooks for a simpler state structure. I created a small example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-example-exsjz?file=/src/queryReducer.js). you can find more reference at [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down)

basically at root from your appplication you would start by creating a context and pass dispatch and query as values to your Provider:

```
export const QueryDispatch = React.createContext("");
const initialState = { query: "" };

export default function App() {
  const [{ query }, dispatch] = useReducer(queryReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <QueryDispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch, query }}>
      <SearchBar />
      <SearchPage />
    </QueryDispatch.Provider>
  );
}
```

where queryReducer could be like:

```
export default function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update':
      return {query: action.query};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and at any component you could consume from your provider:

**at your searchBar**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { QueryDispatch } from "./App";


const SearchBar = () => {
 const const { dispatch, query } = useContext(QueryDispatch);

 const searchQueryHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: "update", query: e.target.value })
 };
      ..code

        <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search spaces of interest"
            className="nav-search"
            value={query}
            onChange={searchQueryHandler} />
```

**and at your SearchPage**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { QueryDispatch } from "./App";

const SearchPage = () => {
  const { query } = useContext(QueryDispatch);
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. However, I'm using typescript in my code and it's showing a syntax error as follows in the app.tsx file : `Type '{ dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>; queries: any; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.`  Can you help me with it? As far as I understand, it's because we have assigned the initial state as `const QueryDispatch = React.createContext("");`

Comment: Okay, I got that. From several answers available on the web, I realized it's a typescript issue and I resolved it by defining an Interface corresponding to the required data types.

Comment: Yep!! everything is working perfectly now. Data is being sent between both the components. I have one more issue though. On refreshing the page will the value of the query get cleared? Is it possible to store it, so that we can you know have it there even when the page is refreshed!

Comment: for data persistence on refresh you can go with `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. mostly your initial state you would go with `const initialState =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('query')) || { query: "" }`. and at some point you would persist redux state on localStorage like `localStorage.setItem('query', JSON.stringify({ query }))`. at your case you may be interested to persist only on form submission. other spots you may be interested to set localState more often. just remember to stringify before setting and parsing before retrieving.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a bunch!